# vue2: @click no effect when i use 'v-show'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**[Here's a link to my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr3nhtv7/2/)**

```js
new Vue( {
  el: "#search",
  data () {
    return {
      s: '',
      show: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search: function () {
      console.log('search')
    },
    hotSearch: function (event) {
      console.log('hot search')
      this.show = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="search">
  <div class='search-bar'>
    <span>
      <input type="text" v-model.trim="s" @keyup.enter="search" 
      @focus="show=true" @blur="show=false" placeholder="search...">
    </span>
    <a @click='search'><span>search</span></a>
    <div v-show="show" id="drop-down-list">
      <em></em>
      <dl class="content">
        <dt>热门搜索：</dt>
        <dd @click="hotSearch">CoolPlay</dd>
        <dd @click="hotSearch">sky fall</dd>
        <dd @click="hotSearch">no man's sky</dd>
        <dd @click="hotSearch">dota2</dd>
        <dd @click="hotSearch">something</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I cilck the "Search" (`<a @click='search'><span>search</span></a>`), the function `search` works.

When I focus the input and click the `dd` element (like  `<dd @click="hotSearch">CoolPlay</dd>`), the function `hotSearch` doesn't work. But when I change `<div v-show="show" id="drop-down-list">` to `<div v-show="true" id="drop-down-list">`, the function `hotSearch` works.

Please tell me where it was wrong and how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: If it works fine with `v-show="true"`, why would you still want to use `v-show="show"`?

Comment: i want to always hide the drop down list, only when i focus on the input, 
the list is visible.if i use `v-show='true'`.the list is always visible.

Comment: ok,  just delete the `@blur="show=false"`.it work.

Comment: Great! Does that solve your problem? It would be good to post below your own answer to share it to other people who might encounter the same problem in the future.